# Diff tool that supports zipped archives

Tags: software-recommendation, tools

I'm searching for a GUI diff application that supports zipped (gz, zip...) file archives, because I want to compare compressed logs. Diffuse, Kdiff3 or Meld don't support that files.

Answer (score 1):

Using `zcat`

```
meld <(zcat file1.gz) <(zcat file2.gz)
```

---

*Example*

```
% cat foo
foo

% cat bar
bar

% gzip foo bar

% meld <(zcat foo.gz) <(zcat bar.gz)
```

[image]

```
% diffuse <(zcat foo.gz) <(zcat bar.gz)
```

[image]

Comment: Not very user-friendly when you are navigating between files in a remote folder from a Filemanager.

Comment: @el_Salmon All that is Open Source. Feel free to make your changes.